# Пожалуйста, очень простой пример, хэш-цепь в Java?

Tags: java

Я ищу очень простой пример криптографической хэш цепи (Hash Chain) исходного кода. Не могли бы вы передать мне некоторые примеры или ссылки, ребята?
Например, h(h(h(h(х)))) дает хэш-цепочку длиной 4. h = хэш, х = пароль.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9 [1]

Comment: почитайте вот это, это то что вы хотите сказать ?? http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-hash-tables-chaining-list-heads/  или есть вариант такой http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Chaining

Comment: Это не криптография метод. Это существующая математическое решение. например,
h(h(h(h(Hello World)))) = d15dadceaa4d5d7bb3b48f446421d542e08ad8887305e28d58335795  Спасибо.

Comment: используйте тогда md5 или sha1 для функции h() и думаю решится ваша задача.